# SSL KafkaAdminClient object using java.security.Keystore object

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, keystore, truststore

I need to create `kafkaAmdinClient` SSL object using `java.security.keystore` object.
i.e I have to read the keystore and truststire files from database as a clob and get the keystore in `java.security.keystore` object and use this to create Admin client object.

I am able to create `AdminClient` object using properties object :

```
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, trustStorePwd);
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/ngs/app/bolt_components/kafka_ssl/RN_BC_YELLOWBIRD/client.truststore.jks");
            props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, keyStorePwd);
                            kafkaAdminClient = AdminClient.create(props);
```

But as per requiremtn i should not specify keystore file location. Instead specify keystore object.

```
KeyStoreDto kDto=KeystoreManager.getKafkaKeyStoreDto(kafkaDto.getKEYSTORE_ID());
            java.security.KeyStore keyStore = kDto.getKeyStore();
            java.security.KeyStore trustStore = kDto.getTrustStore();
            String keyStorePwd=kDto.getKeyStorePassword();
            String trustStorePwd=kDto.getTrustStorePassword();
```

From this i have to use `keyStore` and `trustStore`.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not support `ssl` using `java.security.keystore` object.
You can look into `SslFactory` class at [kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/rest/SslFactory.java) for more information.

Comment: But i dont have a path here, i am reading clob (.jks fie) from databse.                           String keystore_pwd = PasswordService.INSTANCE.decrypt(result.getString("keystore_pwd"));

                dto.setKeyStorePassword(keystore_pwd);
                Blob blob = result.getBlob("keystore_file");
                is = blob.getBinaryStream();
                keyStore.load(is, keystore_pwd.toCharArray());
                dto.setKeyStore(keyStore);

Comment: that's mentioned kafka does not support this.

Comment: ok so is there any other way in which keystore.jks file can be used to create AdminClient object in Kafka through java code if keystore.jks is stored in DB? And workaround?

Comment: Kafka doesn't  support your requirement and there is no alternate for the same.I have provide the link of Kafka source code.You can go through.